# Why created_at updated_at are null on insertion

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project i need to add multiple records at a time an i also want to insert the created_at and updated_at as works in save() automatically.But not working in insert method.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($req->location_id); $i++)
                    {
                            $asset_arr[$i]['property_id'] = $this->id;
                            $asset_arr[$i]['location_id'] = $req->location_id[$i];
                            $asset_arr[$i]['model_id'] = $req->model_id[$i];
                            $asset_arr[$i]['appliance_owner'] = $req->appliance_owner[$i];
                            $asset_arr[$i]['current'] = $req->current[$i];
                            if($req->installdate[$i]!=''){
                                $asset_arr[$i]['installdate'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($req->installdate[$i]));
                            }
                            $asset_arr[$i]['comment'] = $req->comment[$i];
                    }
                    if(!empty($asset_arr)){

                            Asset::insert($asset_arr);
                    }
```

Answer (score 5):

`insert()` is not an Eloquent method, so you'll need to add timestamps manually. Do something like this:

```
$asset_arr[$i]['created_at'] = Carbon::now();
$asset_arr[$i]['updated_at'] = Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Is there any eloquent method to enter multiple records?

Comment: @Alfizamalek no, `insert()` is the only method which allows to insert multiple rows at once.

Comment: Actually, I use create() method inside foreach to add multiple row :)

Comment: @Rashad that will not be bulk insertion.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal ahh okay, got it

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of `insert()` method, you should use `create()`

Laravel's created_at/updated_at are part of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model. `Insert()` is not an eloquent method

Comment: `insert()` is fine there.